# Using Emacs in PuTTY, how do I expand watched structure variable to show struct members in the gud_watch window?

Tags: emacs, gdb, putty, gud

In the [GDB Graphical Interface](http://www.gnu.org/software/libtool/manual/emacs/Watch-Expressions.html) for Emacs
says:

> To expand or contract a complex data type, click Mouse-2 or press <SPC> on the tag to the left of the expression.

**But when I press <kbd>Space</kbd>, the watch window do not expand to show the structure's member.**

**What should I do?**

Also, how can I know whether the **watch expression windows** and **speedbar** is the same thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recently I found, after typing <kbd>Space</kbd>, I need a call, "speedbar-refresh". Then the speedbar window will refresh and expand to show the class members' values.

Comment: speedbar-refresh is bound to 'g' by default. Press <space> then <g> to expand then refresh.

Answer (score 1):

> Each watch expression is displayed in the speedbar

When you use the shell version of Emacs, there is no speedbar. (or, you have to actively switch to it, which isn't practical).

You have to press space in the SpeedBar buffer to get the desired result.

[Emacs W32](http://ourcomments.org/Emacs/EmacsW32.html) + PuTTY/plink works fine over tramp, so there is no need to limit yourself to the shell version, if you don't have to.

Comment: thanks @klang, i can switch to the watch windows, but can not expand the struture by SPACE key.  i'll try "Emacs W32 + PuTTY/plink works fine over tramp"